# CSV to JSON with line breaks with Ruby

Tags: json, ruby, csv

I'm attempting to preserve line breaks when converting CSV to JSON in Ruby.
i have a csv that looks like this:

```
EMAIL, VALUE
some_email@email.com, value1
another_email@email.com, value2 
yet_another_email@email.com, value3
...
```

I need to parse this into JSON, but preserve the row structure so it ends up in a .json file looking like this - there have to be line breaks:

```
{"EMAIL":"some_email@email.com","vars":{"VALUE":"val1"}}
{"EMAIL":"another_email@email.com","vars":{"VALUE":"val2"}}
{"EMAIL":"yet_another_email@email.com","vars":{"VALUE":"val3"}}
```

This is the Ruby code I have so far:

```
temp_json = Tempfile.new

File.open("#{temp_json.path}","w") do |f|
   CSV.foreach('test.csv', headers: :first_row, liberal_parsing: true ).each do |row|
      data = {
        EMAIL: => row.fields[0], 
        vars: => {
          VALUE: => row.fields[1]
        }
      }
      f.write(data.to_json)
    end
  end
```

However, this just creates a file with every element in a single row without the line breaks, like this:
{"EMAIL":"some_email@email.com","vars":{"VALUE":"val1"}}{"EMAIL":"another_email@email.com","vars":{"VALUE":"val2"}}{"EMAIL":"yet_another_email@email.com","vars":{"VALUE":"val3"}}

does anyone know a way to accomplish this?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for `JSON.pretty_generate(x)` instead of `x.to_json`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want JSON, then the line breaks don't matter, but you should be outputting an array:

```
temp_json = Tempfile.new

File.open("#{temp_json.path}","w") do |f|
  # note, map instead of each 
  f.write CSV.foreach("test.csv", headers: :first_row, liberal_parsing: true).map do |row|
    data = {
      EMAIL: row.fields[0], 
      vars: {
        VALUE: row.fields[1]
      }
    }
  end.to_json
end
```

Arrays will suck for really long files, as the whole thing has to be kept in memory and then formatted to JSON. For longer files or if you really want linebreaks for some reason, there is another format called [JSONlines](https://jsonlines.org/) which is closer to CSV. You would write this like this:

```
temp_json = Tempfile.new

File.open("#{temp_json.path}","w") do |f|
  CSV.foreach("test.csv", headers: :first_row, liberal_parsing: true ).each do |row|
    data = {
      EMAIL: row.fields[0], 
      vars: {
        VALUE: row.fields[1]
      }
    }
    f.puts(data.to_json)
  end
end
```

Comment: it's a quirk of the API we're using.  I'll give this a shot.  Thank you!